# low memory opengl

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-management, opengl-es

At each moment I have 3 heavy framebuffers 25mb*3, than I unload one, and load another. And my app crashed at low memory warning. But in allocations tools in xcode I see 90mb used memory every time.
Tested on ipad2 with 500mb RAM. Where is the problem? thanks.

Comment: My guess is your frame buffers have all sorts of other things attached to them as well, but without seeing your setup code, or any code at all, we can only guess.  Please post some code.

Comment: [Allocations can hide memory consumption from OpenGL ES](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5627221/19679), so use the Memory Monitor instrument to get a true look at the memory size of your application. Odds are, you haven't completely removed these framebuffers or their bound textures. Also, just because a device has a certain amount of RAM doesn't mean that all of that is available for your application to use.