# Where can I find the Memory Monitor Instrument on the Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I am having a hard time debugging memory crashed on an GPU-intensive app.

This answer talks about the Memory Monitor Instrument:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10951144/1167349

So does this docu page from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/MemoryMonitorInstrument/MemoryMonitorInstrument.html

However, when I open up Instruments, there is no Memory Monitor to select:
[image: Instruments window]
(yes, I also used the scroll bar)

When I open up the Library, I can not find it there, either. Although the "VM Tracker" and "Shared Memory" instruments have the same icon, they do not provide the same functionality:
[image: Instruments library]

Am I missing something really obvious here??

I am using XCode Version 6.1.1 and Instruments Version 6.1.

Thank you a lot for all answers!

Comment: In Xcode select the "Product" menu point and then choose "Profile". Did you do that? If yes, please explain in your question what you did and where you can't go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I would have loved to include some screenshots, but I am unable because of too low reputation. I am missing exactly 4 points! :D :D

Comment: Have you used the scrollbar on that Instruments window?

Comment: @Droppy Hehe, yes I have scrolled all the way to the bottom. :)

Comment: upvoted to get you over the reputation hump... now post your pix

Comment: What are you trying to use instruments to do? You've mentioned "Memory Monitor" are you trying to see where leaks are occurring?

Comment: The app crashes after using up too much memory, even though the Memory Report (in the debug window) says, it is using around 20 MB constantly.

I would like to find out, if GPU memory is included in this fugure and how much memory I am actually consuming. Several sources (two of them I have linked) say that I can see it in the Memory Monitor Instrument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the Activity Monitor template. Older versions of Instruments had separate monitoring instruments for activity, memory, network usage, and file usage. In Xcode 6 Apple combined these monitoring instruments into one Activity Monitor instrument that you can configure to show the data you are interested in, which is memory usage in your case.

The Activity Monitor instrument is not initially set to graph memory usage. You will have to go to the Record Settings section of the detail view on the right side of the trace window and tell the instrument to graph and list memory usage.

[image]