# For iOS apps, how to use Instruments' Memory Monitor to graph an app's memory usage?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, instruments

It seems that we should rely more on Instruments' "Memory Monitor" (by looking at the app's "Real Memory" number), rather than "Allocations" to tell an app's real memory usage, as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518918/instruments-with-ios-why-does-memory-monitor-disagree-with-allocations).

But for Allocations, we can pause Instruments, and then click on the time-scale bar to get an up-side-down triangle, and drag it to see the highest number of "Live bytes" to tell the peak allocation size -- how about for Memory Monitor, is there a way to also graph the app we are looking at, and be able to tell what the peak memory usage was?

Comment: I'm not sure about graphing, but you can see the moment-to-moment memory usage by selecting the "Track inspection head" option on the lower left of the Instruments interface, under "Process Detail Tracking". Then, when you move the inspection head the memory usage for your application (and other processes) should be what it was at that point in time, not just the last sample taken.

Answer (score -1):

In Instruments, try using **"Activity Monitor"**, that will show how much memory your app is using.

Comment: but you have to look at it second by second to see the maximum used?  Also, what if it shot up to a high value but within the half second it dropped down, then you can't really see it?