# memory usage on IOS 7

Tags: ios7

I'm noticing a huge memory increase when running my application on IOS7. When I run my application in Instruments in XCode 4.6.2, on an iPhone 5 running IOS 6.0.1 I see in Allocations my app is using 12 megs. When running the same code in XCode 5, on a 4S running IOS 7.0.2, I see the memory has risen to over 44 megs. Anyone else seeing this? And if so any idea why this is happening?

Comment: As far as I know it's your app's total memory usage.. To know true live  memory usage u have to use instruments.

Comment: Akshit, I am using instruments. I'm using the Allocation tool from Instruments. I think I mentioned that in my post.

Comment: As a point, [Allocations hides the true memory usage of your application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5627221/19679). Don't use the sizes there to judge the actual size of your application in memory. Use Memory Monitor instead. It's possible that Allocations is more honest in the sizes it reports in iOS 7, because I bet Memory Monitor will show your application being much larger than 12 MB on 6.0.1.