# iOS app killed due to memory limit

Tags: ios, memory, instruments

My app gets killed due to "per-process-limit", however what I see in profiler is quite low

[image]

Do I understand right that the value Im interested in is "Live Bytes" and not "Overall Bytes" ?

In device crash log I see following line:

Name                                           rpages       recent_max       [reason]
          (state)

MyApp        167076           167076  [per-process-limit] (frontmost) (resume)

Comment: OK, if I NSLog current memory usage it prints 60 MB which seems more like a truth, so the question is what "Live Bytes" and "Overall Bytes" are showing?

Comment: Live bytes show the currently allocated bytes and overall shows how much in the lifetime of the app was allocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those numbers depends largely on the filters you've set up, which we can't see from the screenshot.

regardless of that however, you should depend on the Resident Size of the VM Tracker instrument to get a real handle on the memory usage of your app.

the most crucial difference between the two is that Resident Size actually includes all of the memory used by your UIView's backing store for the actual pixel data.

see [this post for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518918/instruments-with-ios-why-does-memory-monitor-disagree-with-allocations).